# No type attribute provided for component property in log4j2 with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, log4j2

I have implemented a simple application for streaming logs to apache kafka.In the producer, I have implemented `log4j2.xml` file for the configuration and now I have to convert `.xml` file into `properties` file. It is working properly with `.xml` but when I use `properties` file then following error has occurred.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:196)
    at com.benz.producer.log.api.LogProducerApplication.main(LogProducerApplication.java:10)
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No type attribute provided for component property
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createComponent(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:334)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.processRemainingProperties(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:348)
```

Here my `.xml` and `properties` files

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<Configuration name="spring-boot-kafka-log" status="info"
                packages="com.benz.producer.log.api">
    <Appenders>
        <Kafka name="Kafka" topic="LOG_TOPIC">
             <PatternLayout pattern="%date  %message"/>
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">
                localhost:9092
            </Property>
        </Kafka>

        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
        </Async>

        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="WARN"/>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

**log4j2.properties**

```
name=spring-boot-kafka-log
status=info
packages=com.benz.producer.log.api
appenders=console,kafka

appender.console.type=console
appender.console.name=stdout
appender.console.target=SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5 [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n

appender.kafka.type=kafka
appender.kafka.name=Kafka
appender.kafka.topic=LOG_TOPIC
appender.kafka.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.kafka.layout.pattern=%date  %message
appender.kafka.property.name=bootstrap.servers
appender.kafka.property.value=localhost:9092

rootLogger.level=INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.ref=kafka
rootLogger.appenderRef.kafka.ref=stdout
logger.name=org.apache.kafka
logger.level=WARN
```

**Updated**

`No type attribute provided for component property` exception is fixed by adding `appender.kafka.property.type=property` into properties file. But when I run again a different error has occurred.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:196)
    at com.benz.producer.log.api.LogProducerApplication.main(LogProducerApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 5
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure your `kafka` logger following the *appenders* configuration:

```
name=spring-boot-kafka-log
status=info
packages=com.benz.producer.log.api
appenders=console,kafka

appender.console.type=console
appender.console.name=stdout
appender.console.target=SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5 [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n

appender.kafka.type=kafka
appender.kafka.name=Kafka
appender.kafka.topic=LOG_TOPIC
appender.kafka.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.kafka.layout.pattern=%date  %message
appender.kafka.property.name=bootstrap.servers
appender.kafka.property.value=localhost:9092

rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRefs = console, kafka
rootLogger.appenderRef.kafka.ref = Kafka
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = stdout

loggers = kafka
logger.kafka.name = org.apache.kafka
logger.kafka.level = WARN
```